# Pytest: Running all tests in test_xyz.py multiple times with different setup. Essentially parametrizing the entire test suite

Tags: python, pytest

I have a bunch of test cases organized by classes in `test_xyz.py`

I have to run these tests with a connection to a remote server(Each test case will be transacting on the said connection).

I have to repeat the same tests multiple times(Each time with different connection credentials). Currently, I manually change the credentials each time and re-run the tests.

I can have the credentials stored in a dictionary. But, how do I automate the tests to run again and again iterating over the credentials stored in the dictionary?

Based on what I read, fixtures might be helpful? But I am not sure.

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

**test_xyz.py example**

```
conn = remote_conn(uname, pwd)

class Test_123:
    """Test Class"""
    
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(...)
    def test_1(self):
        assert conn.do_this()

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(...)    
    def test_2(self):
        assert conn.do_that()
```

Comment: See this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912153/executing-single-unittest-over-a-sequence-in-python/43913387#43913387

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing single unittest over a sequence in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912153/executing-single-unittest-over-a-sequence-in-python)

Comment: @volcano I already have parametrized tests to iterate the same test over a set of values. What I want to do is to essentially parametrize the entire test suite.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Try parametrizing your fixtures. I would suggest to create fixture for your `RemoteConnection` and pass it to the tests. here's how you can do it .

```
import pytest

class RemoteConnection:
    def __init__(self, u, p):
        self.u = u
        self.p = p
        # print "{}-{}".format(u, p)

    def close(self):
        # print "closed"
        pass

    def do_this(self, a):
        # print "do_this {}".format(a)
        return True

    def do_that(self, a):
        # print "do that {}".format(a)
        return True

credentials = [("uname1", "pwd1"), ("uname2", "pwd3"), ("uname3", "pwd3")]
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", params=credentials)
def conn(request):
    _credentials = request.param
    con = RemoteConnection(*_credentials)

    def fin():
        con.close()

    request.addfinalizer(fin)
    return con


class Test_123:
    """Test Class"""

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1, 2])
    def test_1(self, a, conn):
        assert conn.do_this(a)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1, 2])
    def test_2(self, a, conn):
        assert conn.do_that(a)
```

And the sample output from

```
plugins: xdist-1.11, profiling-1.2.6, cov-1.6
collecting ... collected 12 items

../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_1[conn0-1] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_1[conn0-2] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_2[conn0-1] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_2[conn0-2] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_1[conn1-1] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_1[conn1-2] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_2[conn1-1] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_2[conn1-2] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_1[conn2-1] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_1[conn2-2] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_2[conn2-1] PASSED
../../../../../../Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1/scratches/scratch_8.py::Test_123::test_2[conn2-2] PASSED

================= 12 passed, 2 pytest-warnings in 0.08 seconds =================

Process finished with exit code 0
```